# How to merge two column with same data type of a table into one column using PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have found lots of answer to merge two column into one, but I want something like below:

I have a table named A

```
id_one | id_two
---------------
1      | 3
3      | 9
3      | 6
```

I want to combine these two column into one like

```
    id
   ----
    1
    3
    9
    6
```

Comment: do you want alter the structure of your db or just read both ids as one column?

Comment: Please show an example of something you have attempted in merging these columns - you say you have found resources online; what about those resources didn't work for you / what makes your situation unique?

Comment: I found something like this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180207/how-to-merge-two-column-from-same-table
that's why I can't find my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Union` to combine the two column which also removes `duplicates`

```
select id_one from yourtable
union 
select id_two from yourtable
```